# OpenGL - Provide a set of values in a 1D texture

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I want to provide a set of values in a 1D texture. Please consider the following simple example:

```
gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, myTextureHandle);
FloatBuffer values = Buffers.newDirectFloatBuffer(N);

for (int x = 0; x < N; ++x)
    values.put(x);

values.rewind();
gl.glTexImage1D(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL4.GL_R32F, N, 0, GL4.GL_RED, GL4.GL_FLOAT, values);
```

Here, `N` is the amount of values I want to store in the texture. However, calling `textureSize(myTexture, 0)` in my fragment shader yields `1` (no matter to what I set `N`). So, what's going wrong here?

**EDIT:** The code above is executed at initialization. My rendering loop looks like

```
gl.glClear(GL4.GL_COLOR_BIT |GL4.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
gl.glUseProgram(myProgram);
gl.glActiveTexture(MY_TEXTURE_INDEX);
gl.glBindTexture(GL4.GL_TEXTURE_1D, myTextureHandle);
gl.glUniform1i(uMyTexture, MY_TEXTURE_INDEX);
gl.glDrawArrays(GL4.GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
```

My vertex shader consists of a `main`-function which does nothing. I'm using the geometry shader to create a fullscreen quad. The pixel shader code looks like

```
uniform sampler1D myTexture;
out vec4 color;

void main()
{
    if (textureSize(myTexture, 0) == 1)
    {
        color = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
        return;
    }
    color = vec4(1, 1, 0, 1);
}
```

The result is a red-colored window.

Comment: probably something you're not showing. Binding at draw time, shader itself, filtering... is debug_output saying anything?

Comment: @Bahbar I've edited my question to show you everything else what could be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your texture is [complete](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#Creating_a_complete_texture).  Since `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` defaults to `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR` you'll have to supply a full set of mipmaps.

Or set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST`/`GL_LINEAR`.

---

You also need to pass `GL_TEXTURE0 + MY_TEXTURE_INDEX` (instead of only `MY_TEXTURE_INDEX`) to `glActiveTexture()`:

```
gl.glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 + MY_TEXTURE_INDEX );
...
gl.glUniform1i( uMyTexture, MY_TEXTURE_INDEX );
```

Comment: Hm, the values I want to pass to the pixel shader should not be interpolated. I will use texelFetch() to access the values in the 1D texture. So, to what should I set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER`?

Comment: Use `GL_NEAREST` to disable filtering.

Comment: The code example you've linked to recommends to use `glTexStorage2D` and `glTexSubImage2D`. Should I do this instead or stay with my code and set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST`? What's the value of `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` if I use the first method?

Comment: I'd just go with your existing code, it's more compatible.  Even with sampler objects `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` still defaults to `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`.  The texture storage code on the wiki just allocates one mip level and tells OpenGL to only sample from that level.  I guess it's still *technically* mipmapping if there's only one mip level :)

Comment: I've changed my code in the following way: After creating the texture I've bind the texture by `glBindTexture` and set `GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER` to `GL_NEAREST`. However, it's still not working.

Comment: Everything works now. The only thing I need to change was `MY_TEXTURE_INDEX`. Previously, I'd set this value to `1`. If I change it to `0` everything works. I don't understand this. I thought I can set `glActiveTexture` to an arbitrary value, bind a texture using `glBindTexture` and call `glUniform1i` with the same value I've called `glActiveTexture` and everything would work fine.

Comment: You need to pass `GL_TEXTURE0 + MY_TEXTURE_INDEX` to `glActiveTexture()` and just `MY_TEXTURE_INDEX` to `glUniform1i()`.  I suspect if you checked `glGetError()` after your old `glActiveTexture()` call it would have returned `GL_INVALID_ENUM` since `1` is way out of range.  `0` "works" because the active texture state defaults to `GL_TEXTURE0`.

Comment: @genpfault: Maybe you can add that to the answer? The wrong argument go `glActiveTexture()` looks like the main problem.